# Appending Data to Orphan Activities

Tags: activities

We are doing a data migration and are unable to move Attachments related to Activities that don't have a parent. Upon insert we get the dreaded `INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []`

We've been digging into this in the context of `EmailMessages`, which to my knowledge behave as Activities in this context, although they are [technically not Activities](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.activities.htm&language=en_US&type=5). Parent is `RelatedToId`.

The `EmailMessage` inherits permission from the parent; it doesn't have an `OwnerId`. Therefore we are unable to grant access via parent in Sharing Settings, or by `UserRole`.

I also tried throwaway test code (please forgive sins such as seealldata=true):

```
    @istest(seealldata=true)
    public static void blankParent(){
        EmailMessage em = [SELECT Id FROM EmailMessage WHERE RelatedToId = null LIMIT 1];
        Account a = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1];
        em.RelatedToId = a.Id;
        update em;
        System.debug([SELECT Id, RelatedToId FROM EmailMessage WHERE Id =: em.Id]);
    }
```

This gives: `System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: EmailMessage.RelatedToId`

We get similar results when using proper Activities like Tasks with WhatId.

The only course of action seems to be to set the parent to a dummy Account when the RelatedToId is null during the migration, so the records are inserted with some kind of parent, but we won't be able to remove it after the fact.

Does anyone know of a way to gain permissions to these orphan Activities so I can insert Attachments?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Just to confirm - you're talking about the old Attachment object and not the newer ContentVersion / ContentDocument Link objects, right?

Comment: @DavidCheng that's correct.